# flutter bottom buttons and TextInputType overflows when keyboard is displayed

Tags: flutter, keyboard, overflow

I have a screen with an icon button at the bottom and some textfield. The app shall work on all devices on all resolutions.

When selecting the text input field, the keyboard will be displayed. The canvas will be smaller and on a mobile phone I got an overflow error.

Alternatives which I have tried already:

- When wrapped the column in a SingleChildScrollView, there is a render issue.
- When setting resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false as scaffold property, the button will disappear when the keyboard is displayed
- When adding the button to persistentFooterButtons in the scaffold widget, the button disappear when the keyboard is displayed
- When using a ListView instead of a column, I cannot use the Expanded widget to enforce the button to the bottom

```
Column(children: <Widget>[
  TextField(),
  TextField(),
  TextField(),
  TextField(),
  TextField(),
  Expanded(child: Container()),
  IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.add_comment), onPressed: () => print("pressed"))
])
```

I want to have something that scrolls the content. The user shall have access to the button, no matter if the keyboard is displayed or not

Comment: Could you provide more detail of these widgets?

Comment: i think there's  a problem with the parent of the Column you used, may be if you can give the complete example, it'll be easier to find the problem

Comment: 'return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text("example"),
  ),
  body: 
    Column(children: <Widget>[
      TextField(),
      TextField(),
      TextField(),
      TextField(),
      TextField(),
      Expanded(child: Container()),
      IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.add_comment), onPressed: () => print("pressed"))
    ]));
  }'

Comment: try resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false on your scaffold.